# How to load a webpage compleately in python using pdfkit

Tags: python, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I want to create a PDF from webpage. So I used pdfkit, but it doesn't load the full webpage.
It creates the PDF, but some part of the text aren't loaded completely.

Comment: Can you please share the code you've used so far? And an example of what went wrong

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.